# Do not settag for new items that is added into listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

Help me please! My English's level not good.
I have override getView() function bellow:

```
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewObjectHolder viewObjectHolder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.row_list_menu, parent, false);
        viewObjectHolder = new ViewObjectHolder();
        viewObjectHolder.tvNameDrink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvNameDrink);
        viewObjectHolder.tvPriceDrink = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvPriceNameDrink);
        viewObjectHolder.tvNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvnumber);
        viewObjectHolder.btnInc = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInc);
        viewObjectHolder.btnDec = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDec);
        viewObjectHolder.tvTotalPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvToltalPrice);

        convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDec).setTag(position);
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInc).setTag(position);
        convertView.setTag(viewObjectHolder);

    } else {
        viewObjectHolder = (ViewObjectHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    setViewObject(viewObjectHolder, position);

    return convertView;
}

public void setViewObject(ViewObjectHolder viewObjectHolder, int position) {
    Object_List_Menu object_list_menu = list_object_menus.get(position);
    viewObjectHolder.tvNameDrink.setText(String.valueOf(position + 1));
    viewObjectHolder.tvNameDrink.setText(object_list_menu.getStrNameDrink());
    viewObjectHolder.tvPriceDrink.setText(object_list_menu.getStrPriceDrink());
    viewObjectHolder.tvNumber.setText(object_list_menu.getStrNumber());
    viewObjectHolder.btnInc.setText(object_list_menu.getStrInc());
    viewObjectHolder.btnDec.setText(object_list_menu.getStrDec());
    viewObjectHolder.tvTotalPrice.setText(object_list_menu.getStrTotalPrice());
}
```

row_list_menu.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvNameDrink"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:text="Cafe"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPriceNameDrink"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"
        android:text="40"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="62dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvnumber"
        android:layout_width="133dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="69dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tvInc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClickBtnInc"
            android:text="^"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tvDec"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="onClickBtnDnc"
            android:text="v"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvToltalPrice"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:text="0"
        android:textSize="@dimen/font_size" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I added a item to file(external storage) and load into listview. Then, I add new item to file, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() update lisview. When I add new item, getView() function is called and this time convertview is null, but the first item is existed in listview will settag. So new item do not settag() because convertview != null. Tag of new item will get the first item in listview. onclick() on btnInc or btnDec of new item will change value on the first item in listview. When I restart program, the program works correctly. 
I Want this program work correctly when this time. I added new item and do not restart program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're assigning the list position as the tag of the buttons for incrementing and decrementing inside the if block which will only be reached when creating a new view, not when it is being reused. I don't see the click handler posted with your question, but if that tag is being used in the button click handler, the position will correspond to the view's position in the list when it was first created, not it's current position which could be your issue.

Moving these assignments

```
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnDec).setTag(position);
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnInc).setTag(position);
```

inside setViewObject(..) will likely solve the problem.

Also, I'd recommend assigning tags to views using a generated view id, not setting the global tag for a view since that may collide with other implementations interacting with that view.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(int,%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: I moved two row above into setViewObject() function. it run correctly. Thank you so much! Your comment I will pay attention